# SQL Pivot and Group By By Date and Totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-pivot

I am using SQL Server 13.0 Developer Edition.
I can't make the correct structure for the SQL code with Pivot and Group by clauses.

I have data like;

| Id | OperationType | Date | ResultCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BeginTransaction | 2022-12-01 16:54:30 | -28 |
| 2 | BeginTransaction | 2022-12-02 18:54:30 | -30 |
| 3 | BeginTransaction | 2022-12-02 18:54:30 | -30 |
| 4 | BeginTransaction | 2022-12-03 14:54:30 | -10 |
| 5 | BeginTransaction | 2022-12-03 11:54:30 | -5 |
| 6 | BeginTransaction | 2022-12-05 10:54:30 | -3 |

and I want to see total number of ResultCodes per day but I want to generate ResultCode columns dynamicly because I have so much different result codes. Query result should be like;

| Day | -3 | -5 | -10 | -28 | -30 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-01 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-12-02 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 2022-12-03 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 2022-12-05 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I wrote this query but it says `The incorrect value "ResultCode" is supplied in the PIVOT operator.`

```
Select * from (SELECT CAST(Date as date),
COUNT(ResultCode) as Result,
       COUNT(*) AS Totals
FROM OperationLogs 
WHERE OperationType = 'Begin'
GROUP BY CAST(StartTime as date)
) As Source
PIVOT (
COUNT(Result) FOR Result IN ([ResultCode])
) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY ForDate
```

Can anyone help me with how can I group by date and also have counts for ResultCodes as colums and a Total by day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #ResultCodes (
Id INT,
OperationType VARCHAR(50),
[Date] DateTime,
ResultCode INT
)

INSERT INTO #ResultCodes(Id,OperationType,[Date],ResultCode) VALUES
(1,'BeginTransaction','2022-12-01 16:54:30',-28),
(2,'BeginTransaction','2022-12-02 18:54:30',-30),
(3,'BeginTransaction','2022-12-02 18:54:30',-30),
(4,'BeginTransaction','2022-12-03 14:54:30',-10),
(5,'BeginTransaction','2022-12-03 11:54:30',-5),
(6,'BeginTransaction','2022-12-05 10:54:30',-3)

DECLARE @COLUMNS AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @QUERY  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    
SET @COLUMNS = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(ResultCode) 
             FROM #ResultCodes GROUP BY ResultCode ORDER BY ResultCode DESC
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
             ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
         ,1,1,'')

SET @QUERY = N'
    SELECT [Date],'+@COLUMNS+', tc AS "Total"    
    FROM (
      SELECT
        [tc] = COUNT(CAST([Date] AS date)) over(partition by CAST([Date] AS date)),
        CAST([Date] AS date) AS "Date", 
        [ResultCode]
      FROM #ResultCodes
    ) AS tb 
    PIVOT (
      COUNT([ResultCode])
      FOR [ResultCode]
      IN (
        '+@COLUMNS+'
      )
    ) AS P'; 

EXEC(@QUERY)

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ResultCodes
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can find the answer here : https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-pivot-tables-in-sql-server/ 
and below

```
USE [tempdb] 
IF OBJECT_ID ('[Date]') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [Date] 
CREATE TABLE [Date] ([Id] int , [OperationType] varchar(50) , [Date] datetime  , [ResultCode] int) 
INSERT INTO [Date] VALUES (1, 'BeginTransaction', '2022-12-01 16:54:30', -28)    , (2, 'BeginTransaction', '2022-12-02 18:54:30', -30)   , (3, 'BeginTransaction', '2022-12-02 18:54:30', -30)   , (4, 'BeginTransaction', '2022-12-03 14:54:30', -10)   , (5, 'BeginTransaction', '2022-12-03 11:54:30', -5)    , (6, 'BeginTransaction', '2022-12-05 10:54:30', -3)

DECLARE @pivotcolumns varchar(500) = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CAST([ResultCode] AS varchar(20))) FROM [Date] GROUP BY [ResultCode] ORDER BY [ResultCode] FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

DECLARE @SqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)   
SET @SqlStatement = N'
    SELECT * , SUM('+REPLACE(@pivotcolumns, ',', '+')+') OVER (PARTITION BY CAST([Date] AS date)) AS "Total"     FROM (
      SELECT
        CAST([Date] AS date) AS "Date", [ResultCode]
      FROM [Date]
    ) AS t1
    PIVOT (
      COUNT([ResultCode])
      FOR [ResultCode]
      IN (
        '+@pivotcolumns+'
      )
    ) AS PivotTable
      ';
EXEC(@SqlStatement)
```

Comment: As you can see from above I know how to write the code and I obviously searched internet. But I still got an error, that is why I asked the question.

Comment: The artical I link you to show you how to generate columns dynamicly - my answer is valid. Giv me 10m and I'll write you the code :)

Comment: FYI, the solution you use here is a [documented antipattern](//docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) and should be avoided; it relies on the data engine processing your in a row by row order, which there is *no* guarantee of. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. In recent versions of SQL Server that would be by using `STRING_AGG`, however, in older versions you'll need to use `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) to achieve the same results.

Comment: @Larnu - I did not want to suggest STRING_AGG as SQL Server version was not specified. I'll se if I can find the code for FOR XML PATH. Thanks.

Comment: I (and some others) tend to *assume* a fully supported version of the software when a version is omitted, @johndk , and `STRING_AGG` is supported in both 2019 and 2022.